# Issue in function invoked by setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Below is the code snippet from my backbone application. I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: this.toastMsg is not a function" error on running it. But if I directly call the method this.checkUserAction() it is working fine. when I invoke from setInterval() it is throwing that error.

```
var clock;//Global variable

initialize : function(){
    clock = setInterval(this.checkUserAction,1000);
}

checkUserAction : function(){
    this.toastMsg("Sucess");
},
//Displays message on top of the window
toastMsg : function(msg){
    $(".msgText").text(msg);
    $(".alert").show("slide", { direction: "up"  }, 1000);
}
```

> getting error : Uncaught TypeError: this.toastMsg is not a function

Comment: `checkUserAction` is executed in global context, that is, `this` doesn't point to your expected object instance. Googling for bind pops up the following tutorial: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
clock = setInterval(this.checkUserAction,1000);
```

With

```
var self = this;
clock = setInterval(function(){self.checkUserAction()},1000);
```

Comment: *"In your code this.checkUserAction returns the function itself."* - Why is that a problem? setInterval() expects a function as its first argument. And clearly it manages to call that function, because the error relates to the code inside it.

Comment: @nnnnnn I added an anonymous function inside setInterval and tested in my standalone backbone project. Then it started working. You are right ,In both the cases we are passing a function to setInterval().